# Gapped sentences

Tags: word-request

Reading a gapped sentence aloud, what should we say to denote the part which is actually a gap?

For example, *Gillian decided it was time to turn over a new _______ and forget her past mistakes.* I heard people say *"...new hm-hm-hm and..."* But is there anything better than that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would use the word "blank" and read you sentence aloud like this:

> Gillian decided it was time to turn over a new **blank** and forget her past mistakes.

Here are two relevant definitions (M-W):

> [blank](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/blank)
>   2 a : an empty space (as on a paper)
>   5 : a dash substituting for an omitted word